# What makes this question off topic?

Tags: discussion

[How to avoid walking into others in busy hallways?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/125/how-to-avoid-walking-into-others-in-busy-hallways)

Interacting with others in a hallway seems to be an interpersonal skill...

What makes this off topic?

Comment: to be totally honest, I think it could be on topic, it just needs to be reworded.

Answer (score 1):

That question is on topic.
It was already on-topic even before being edited.

Some seem to think that all questions here have to involve talking to people. It is not the case.

The question we are talking about asks how to avoid being rude (or more exactly how to avoid being perceived as rude). Rudeness is totally an interpersonal skill, you are never rude if you live alone on a deserted island, and the concept of rudeness appears as soon as you have to live with other persons. So, is there actually anything more on topic here than this? :

- Getting a knowledge of what is considered rude or not
- Becoming able to realize when your own behavior could be seen as rude
- Modifying your own behavior in consequence

And that's exactly what that question is about.

So, questions about how to not appear rude are definitely on topic.

Answer (score -2):

The way the question worded currently does not obviously show how it relates to Interpersonal Skill.

> How do I navigate around large groups of people clogging up hallways without being perceived as rude? Usually I can see people coming from a distance and change my route to avoid them, but, sometimes there are right angles in the hallway in which case there is no easy way to avoid them if they are walking on the wrong side.

Read the first sentence and you'll see.

In my personal opinion, this is within the scope of Interpersonal Skill Stackexchange, but this is very basic (a novice question, perhaps? No offense) and does not reflect how expert this site should have **on the private beta**.

> The first questions set the tone for the site. If you ask high quality, expert-level questions, you'll build a site that attracts the experts and pros who will make it really successful. **But if you ask beginner questions**, survey questions, or social-conversation questions, experts and pros will not be interested.
>   *Interpersonal Skills.SE private beta email invitation*

Comment: Good point. I'll re ask after the private beta more consicely. No offense taken

Comment: Can you please source your quotes? Where do you come up with this idea that private beta is for magical "expert" questions? Who are the experts in this topic, anyway?

Comment: @Catija I believe you got an email invitation to the private beta. It is written there, and when you first use the site in private beta. As in expert, I believe nobody here would call themselves "expert", but there are certainly people with far more interpersonal skills and experience than us, which qualifies us to call them "expert", though they don't call themselves one.

Comment: If that content is from the email, please note that in your answer. Quote boxes imply that you're quoting information, as such, you should link to or at least note where you found it. That blurb is the same for every SE that goes into Beta. It's not applicable to every site. Everyone who interacts with other people on a regular basis is an "expert" in this topic to some degree. I'm pretty sure that we aren't expecting this site to be populated with professional advice columnists.

Comment: There's nothing necessarily wrong with asking a novice question provided that the question is asked in good faith and the answer helps people. Everyone has their blindspots, what seems novice to one may seem advanced to another. Let's not be too quick to shut down "easier" questions.