# Deletion or incorrect close votes?

Tags: discussion

From this question [What makes this question off topic?](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65/what-makes-this-question-off-topic)

I realized that we are trying to get the best questions during the beta. Mine clearly wasn't the most well thought out question and it made more sense in my head, but, now what should I do?

Should I delete the question?
Should I let it sit with an incorrect close vote?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you think Beta is about getting the "best" questions? Beta is when we decide what's in scope and how questions work. That requires getting both good and bad questions so that the site can decide what should be welcome and what should be off topic or closed for some other reason.

These "bad" questions are arguably more important to the site than "good" questions. They act as a signpost and show us where and how to improve.

I encourage you to leave the question. By asking about it in meta (as you have now, twice) we discuss and explain why questions are good or bad and that informs others. If you delete the question, that information is lost except to high-rep users, of which there really aren't any at this point.

Additionally, if the question was closed as being "off topic", follow the instructions... edit the question to explain how it's about interpersonal relations... editing it will put it in the reopen review queue and if users agree that it's now on topic, they will vote to reopen it. This is how SE works!

---

As a note, because the question has positively-scoring answers, you wouldn't be able to delete it if you tried.

Answer (score 2):

That's entirely up to you. You can always edit it in the future to reopen it. On the plus side if you delete it you will earn a fancy bronze badge.

However you should **always** aim to ask the best questions you can. If you don't think it was that good think of how to improve it, rather than just reposting it in the future.

Comment: Can't delete it. It has answers with positive votes.

Comment: @catija in which case he can flag it for mod assistance :3

Comment: And any mod would decline that flag. There is no reason to delete this content.

Comment: It's his post. In my opinion as it's his content he can do what he likes. I've been able to delete my own accepted answers in the past by flagging them.